# MapBox: Why extends GeoJson Featuregroup which in turn extends Layergroup if it represents a layer?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I don't get the inheritance-freaky mapbox API:

> **GeoJson**
>   Represents a GeoJSON layer. Extends *FeatureGroup*.
>
> **FeatureGroup**
>   Extended *layerGroup* ...
>
> **LayerGroup**
>   Used to group several layers ...

This looks like a cycle to me. Somebody can make sense of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laeflet (and the mapbox variant of leaflet), some layers can also act as layer containers (group layers), namely:

```
 LayerGroup
 FeatureGroup
 GeoJSON
```

Other layers, like the tile layer, do not have the ability to contain other layers.

Answer (score 0):

> This looks like a cycle to me.

It would be if the last link connected, but layerGroup is the lowest it goes. This is just [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/)'s way of doing things: layerGroup [provides the basic add/remove](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) API, [featureGroup supports mouse events and popups](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup), [geojson supports, as you might guess, the GeoJSON format](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson).

These levels of inheritance exist because you might not want all of them: if you aren't dealing with geojson, just use a featuregroup. if you just want to group layers that don't have popups (like, for instance, tile layers), just use a layergroup.

Comment: since layer extends layer group, does that mean that a layer can be a container for other layers? in pattern lingua, is it a compositum?

Comment: 'Layer' is not a type. Otherwise, you are confusing inheritance with composition: because layerGroup inherits from something does not mean that it contains the thing.

Comment: i am certainly not confusing inheritance with composition. in fact leaflet layers adhere to the composition pattern. so a layer contains other layers.

Comment: Sounds like you've got it all figured out, then!